# How to attach NGBootstrap tooltip to font awesome icon

Tags: javascript, css, angular, font-awesome, ng-bootstrap

Trying to add a tooltip to a font awesome icon in an Angular page.  The normal Bootstrap method seems to be ignored so I am trying to use the NGBootstrap method used for adding a tooltip to buttons, but the tool tip never displays.  https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/tooltip/examples

The typical Bootstrap method causes an error of Cannot set property 'title' of undefined when hovering.

```
<i class="fa fa-info-circle" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Name here"></i>
```

In the component:

```
ngafterviewinit() {
    $(function() {
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
    }
};
```

Comment: Have you tried using a <span> element instead of <i>?

Comment: Error was coming from somewhere else, fixed that. But still not getting a nice looking tooltip, just the default browser one, with <i> and with <span>.

Answer (score -1):

You can also try using button tag.

```
<div class="infoCSSClass">
    <button class="icon-info" data-container="body" ngbTooltip="Here is tooltip text"  #toolTip="ngbTooltip"  (click)="toolTip.open()" placement="top"></button>
</div>
```

Comment: That just creates a large button, not a small icon.  I could make it a small button but more of a hack than making the icon be the trigger.

Comment: Using CSS, you can handle the button display. Its not wrong answer.

Answer (score -1):

This seems to work:

```
<i id="icon" class="fa fa-1x fa-info-circle" [ngClass]="icon" aria-hidden="true" placement="right" ngbTooltip="tipContent"></i>
```